# looking for an iso with wireless driver included

Tags: drivers, wireless, iso

"isthere an ubuntuor lubuntu iso with broadcom bcm94360 cd wireless card driver included available for download?"  THANKS

Comment: What driver works with it?

Comment: Any Ubuntu ISO for a specific release/architecture will contain the same kernel modules as *flavors* like your listed Lubuntu. Sure for some LTS releases (eg. 22.04 & 22.04.1) they install with different defaults (Ubuntu Desktop installs with HWE, Lubuntu/Xubuntu with GA in comparison) but the kernel modules (aka *drivers*) on the ISO are identical and thus they differ only after upgrades are applied. On a *live* system I'm unaware of any difference between Ubuntu or any *flavor* of the same product/release/architecture.